# FreeSWITCH can't parse XML with serving mod_python

Tags: python, freeswitch, mod-python

I'm trying to serve XML configuration through mod_python in FreeSWITCH. However, sometimes FreeSWITCH can't parse my XML and sometimes it can.

I am sure my XML config is true, I created a static file internal.xml with the same XML that I am serving with mod_python. I am using FS v1.8 and Debian 9.7 and the same code is working fine with FreeBSD and FS v1.6.
What would cause this issue?

You can see the logs of `sofia profile external start` command. https://pastebin.freeswitch.org/view/1bc47b2b

The part of the code that I'm using to create XML(using lxml).
https://pastebin.freeswitch.org/view/9ed466f5

Comment: Are you sure you're setting external profile correctly?
It seems it's lacking maybe correct realm configuration or that there's an IP mismatch for external profile.

Comment: I am using the same configuration with FreeBSD and FSv1.8 and it does work without issues. In my new setup, it does parse my profile correctly sometimes and it's not just only profile XML it can't read dialplan configurations as well.